# PHP gmdate to timestamp

Tags: php, date

i have a date string in the following format January 1, 1970 , i am having trouble converting it back to a timestamp format

i have tried using Datetime to no avail

```
$test=new DATETIME($expire_date);
echo date_timestamp_get( $test);
```

i know that this was made by using the code

```
<?php
gmdate("F j, Y", $date_created)
```

How do i format it back into a time stamp so i can compare with today date
e.g.

```
<?php
if (time()>$timestamp){
//do something
}
```

Comment: u could use gmddate()

Answer (score 0):

You need use `DateTime::format()` with the `U` parameter as `$test` is a DateTime object and not a regular date string:

```
$timestamp = $test->format('U');
```

Or, better yet, just compare DateTime objects (I changed the variable names to makie the ode easier to read):

```
$expires = new DateTime($expire_date);
$now     = new DateTime();

if ($now > $expires){
//do something
}
```